# Using normalised table schema of RDS directly in Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse

Is it okay using normalised table schema of RDS directly in Redshift? Some articles says that one should use dimension modelling like star schema, etc in data warehouse?

I have 30-40 tables. My tables data is not in too large to be in billions. At most I think few tables (2-3) would have 1.5 million rows. The rest all relatively small.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on the kind and complexity of queries you run, and how often.

Comment: Amazon Redshift is an SQL database, so you can certainly use normalised schemas! If you are asking about performance, then it is something you can play with by setting an appropriate DISTKEY and SORTKEY (although this can be automatic these days). Wide tables can be useful for building simpler queries and can operate faster due to them having less JOINs.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - by wide tables you meant star schema, fact table, etc ? Assume I don't want to learn any of those data warehouse concepts, just use same schema as in RDS, and run queries on them, is this completely fine ?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - i just want to combine 2-3 rds dbs in one redshift db & run queries on them using joins like in oltp sql

Comment: A 'wide table' is a completely de-normalized table (the opposite of a star schema). Using Orders as an example, a star schema would have one table with Orders, another table with Order Items, another table for Addresses, etc. A 'wide table' would instead contain one line per Order Item with information about Order, Customer, Address duplicated on every line. This makes it very easy to query because there is little/no need to use JOINs. Modern data warehouses can store and query such tables efficiently.

Comment: **Bottom line:** You can use Redshift in any way you want. It is excellent at querying, but rather poor if you want to use it for OLTP (eg inserts, deletes, updates). People typically use a database like Postgres until it hits performance limits, then move to a Data Warehouse like Redshift when they want more performance for querying large quantities of data. If RDS works for you, then keep using it. If it is causing problems due to data size and performance, use something like Redshift.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - Thanks for so much info. I want to use Redshift only for querying (no insert, delete, update) but do not want to use wide table schema. But like you said, I can use it in normalised form too. Again thanks!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - If you add this as an answer, I would accept it as correct and close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Redshift in any way you want.

It is excellent at **querying**, but rather poor if you want to use it for **OLTP** (eg inserts, deletes, updates).

People typically use a database like Postgres until it hits performance limits, then move to a Data Warehouse like **Amazon Redshift** when they want more performance for querying large quantities of data.

If **Amazon RDS** works for you, then keep using it. If it is causing problems due to data size and performance, then shift to Amazon Redshift. (It's more expensive, but has better performance.)

Another option is to use **Amazon Athena**, which has no 'running costs' -- you just pay per query. If the data is stored in an Amazon S3 bucket in **Snappy-compressed Parquet format** it will run very fast and cost very little. It is similar to "Redshift Spectrum". Athena can also handle any type of table (wide, star) but doesn't really handle updates/inserts.

Comment: I want to connect this combined db to metabase. Can Athena be connected to metabase in anyway?

Comment: [Metabase: Amazon Athena](https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/databases/connections/athena)